# How can I re-create a nested JSON structure from a Key-Value paired dictionry (where key represents PATH)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate a JSON like structure from following key-value paired dictionary

**NOTE**: *You can IGNORE The actual data attached to the keys. Data attached to each of the examples will be different since I executed the program several times to get all of these examples printed. The problem remains however.*

(***NOTE** that key here represent path to each leaf NODE, while the value represents data that needs to be attached in the resulting dictionary. Also, the |FALSE| or |TRUE| appended to each element is there just as a heuristic to specify whether or not the node is an ARRAY or not*):

```
{
  FirstName: [ 'Penelope' ],
  LastName: [ 'Veum' ],
  BusinessPartnerCategory: [ '1' ],
  SearchTerm1: [ 'DZBANK456' ],
  CorrespondenceLanguage: [ 'EN' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.InternationalLocationNumber1': [ '0' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.CustomerAccountGroup': [ 'CUST' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.SalesOrganization': [ '1710' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.DistributionChannel': [ '10' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Division': [ '00' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Currency': [ 'EUR' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.ItemOrderProbabilityInPercent': [ '100' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.CompleteDeliveryIsDefined': [ false ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Country': [ 'US' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.CityName': [ 'Atlanta' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Region': [ 'GA' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.PostalCode': [ '30303' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.StreetName': [ '543 Peachtree Street' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.IsDefaultEmailAddress': [ true ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.EmailAddress': [ '{{FirstName}}.{{LastName}}@gmail.com' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.AddressCommunicationRemarkText': [ 'the' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerRole|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.BusinessPartnerRole': [ 'FLCU00' ]
}
```

What I am expecting to see is:

```
{
    "FirstName": "Jarrell",
    "LastName": "Bode",
    "BusinessPartnerCategory": "1",
    "SearchTerm1": "DZBANK456",
    "CorrespondenceLanguage": "EN",
    "to_BusinessPartnerRole": {
        "results": [
            {
                "BusinessPartnerRole": "FLCU00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "to_BusinessPartnerAddress": {
        "results": [
            {
                "to_EmailAddress": {
                    "results": [
                        {
                            "IsDefaultEmailAddress": true,
                            "EmailAddress": "Jarrell.Bode@gmail.com",
                            "AddressCommunicationRemarkText": "whoa"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Country": "US",
                "CityName": "Atlanta",
                "Region": "GA",
                "PostalCode": "30303",
                "StreetName": "543 Peachtree Street"
            }
        ]
    },
    "to_Customer": [
        {
            "InternationalLocationNumber1": "0",
            "to_CustomerSalesArea": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "SalesOrganization": "1710",
                        "DistributionChannel": "10",
                        "Division": "00",
                        "Currency": "USD",
                        "ItemOrderProbabilityInPercent": "100",
                        "CompleteDeliveryIsDefined": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            "CustomerAccountGroup": "CUST"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code that I've wrote for reconstructing the dictionary:

```
const final_result = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < quantity; index++) {
          let response_cpy = Object.assign({}, response_new);
          for (const [path, data] of Object.entries(pathDataDict)) {
            const pathSplit = path.split(".");
            pathSplit.reduce(function (response: any, incompleteKey: any) {
              const keySplit = incompleteKey.split("|");
              const actualKey = keySplit[0];
              if (actualKey === pathSplit[pathSplit.length - 1]) {
                if (
                  typeof response === "object" &&
                  !Array.isArray(response) &&
                  response !== null
                ) {
                  return (response[actualKey] = (data as any)[index]);
                } else {
                  return (response[0][actualKey] = (data as any)[index]);
                }
              }  else {
                return (
                  response[actualKey] ||
                  (keySplit.length > 1 && keySplit[1] === "TRUE"
                    ? (response[actualKey] = [{}])
                    : (response[actualKey] = {}))
                );
              }
            }, response_cpy);
          }
          final_result.push(response_cpy);
        }
```

Problem with this code is that it generates monkey patched attributes - if an element in a path-data dictionary is NOT a LEAF node, it will create an attribute for an array instead. For example, if I were to `console.log(final_result[0])` I would get:

```
{
    "FirstName": "Imelda",
    "LastName": "Powlowski",
    "BusinessPartnerCategory": "1",
    "SearchTerm1": "DZBANK456",
    "CorrespondenceLanguage": "EN",
    "to_BusinessPartnerRole": {
        "results": [
            {
                "BusinessPartnerRole": "FLCU00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "to_BusinessPartnerAddress": {
        "results": [
            {
                "Country": "US",
                "CityName": "New York",
                "Region": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10007",
                "StreetName": "1681 Broadway "
            }
        ]
    },
    "to_Customer": [
        {
            "InternationalLocationNumber1": "0",
            "CustomerAccountGroup": "CUST"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can clearly see that some of the attributes (which are NOT LEAF NODES, but objects) are missing. Even further, if I were to `console.log(final_result[0].to_BusinessPartnerAddress.results)` I would see an Array like object which has an object for an element and a MONKEY PATCHED attribute like so:

```
[
  {
    Country: 'US',
    CityName: 'New York',
    Region: 'NY',
    PostalCode: '10007',
    StreetName: '1681 Broadway '
  },
  to_EmailAddress: { results: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

What is wrong with my code exactly? How can I re-create original JSON like structure without losing any of the parts?

Comment: This isn't JSON - having said that,  how does `FirstName: [ 'Penelope' ],  LastName: [ 'Veum' ],` become `"FirstName": "Jarrell", "LastName": "Bode",` and then `"FirstName": "Imelda", "LastName": "Powlowski",`

Comment: Sorry, data generated in these examples were different. The principle and the problem is the same though. I will put a note in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the paths and loop parts, creating needed nodes (object or arrays based on TRUE/FALSE):

```js
const obj = Object.entries(source).reduce((r, [key, [val]]) => {
  let node = r;
  const path = key.split('.'), prop = path.pop();
  path.forEach(part => {
    const [prop, isArray] = part.split('|');
    isArray === 'TRUE' ? node = (node[prop] ??= [])[0] ??= {} : node = node[prop] ??= {};
  });
  node[prop] = val;
  return r;
}, {});      

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script>
const source = {
  FirstName: [ 'Penelope' ],
  LastName: [ 'Veum' ],
  BusinessPartnerCategory: [ '1' ],
  SearchTerm1: [ 'DZBANK456' ],
  CorrespondenceLanguage: [ 'EN' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.InternationalLocationNumber1': [ '0' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.CustomerAccountGroup': [ 'CUST' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.SalesOrganization': [ '1710' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.DistributionChannel': [ '10' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Division': [ '00' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Currency': [ 'EUR' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.ItemOrderProbabilityInPercent': [ '100' ],
  'to_Customer|TRUE|.to_CustomerSalesArea|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.CompleteDeliveryIsDefined': [ false ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Country': [ 'US' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.CityName': [ 'Atlanta' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.Region': [ 'GA' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.PostalCode': [ '30303' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.StreetName': [ '543 Peachtree Street' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.IsDefaultEmailAddress': [ true ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.EmailAddress': [ '{{FirstName}}.{{LastName}}@gmail.com' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.to_EmailAddress|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.AddressCommunicationRemarkText': [ 'the' ],
  'to_BusinessPartnerRole|FALSE|.results|TRUE|.BusinessPartnerRole': [ 'FLCU00' ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: This seems to work, and it looks elegant enough. Thanks! I will study this solution

Comment: Quick question, what if I had an array of multiple values? E.g., for the FirstName: ['Penelope', 'David', 'Martin'] I believe this case covers only arrays with single values, correct?

Comment: @CodingAddict yes, if you like the answer being fixed for that case please fix the question with the needed input and output

Comment: I think I know how to solve it tbh, if I run into any issues I will do just that. Thanks!

Comment: @CodingAddict yes, seems not hard to tweak the code to cover the case